# Отследить закрытие SearchView Android

Tags: android, search

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отследить закрытие SearchView, производится нажатием на стрелку.Но отследить это нажатие не получается, использую этот листенер.

```
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startMode(Mode.NORMAL);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Really?");
        }
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте повесить OnCloseListener на SearchView:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ТУТ_ВАШЕ_МЕНЮ, menu);

final MenuItem searchMI = menu.findItem(R.id.АЙДТШНИК_ПОИСКА_В_РАЗМЕТКЕ_МЕНЮ);
if(searchView == null) {
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMI);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Закрыто");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает.